# Constraint Labels in CPLEX for Java?

Tags: java, cplex

in CPLEX Optimization Studio, I can label constraints to identify the reasons for an infeasibility more quickly.

=> Is there a similar thing for the Java API?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Christopher

Answer (score 0):

To label constraints

1. create a variable IloRange or IloConstraint
2. link the actual constraint to this variable
3. give the constraint a name

```js
IloRange rng;
rng = cplex.addLe(X[i],1);
rng.setName("My name for variable X_" + i);
```

Please note, if there are variables on both sides of the constraint, you have to use IloConstraint instead of IloRange. In general, it is however useful to use the more precise class (IloRange instead of IloConstraint) as explained in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400056

Answer (score 0):

just realised, it is possible to set a name directly instead of creating an additional variable before just like

```js
cplex.addLe(X[i],1).setName()
```